# CSS grid column not starting and ending where expected

Tags: css, css-grid

New to CSS grid and running into a strange issue. Take a look at the codepen demo I put together: https://codepen.io/bmarshall511/pen/OjYXZJ

Same CSS applied to two different divs (`.grid-3-10`), one with and h1 and one with a p, yet they start in different places. Can't figure out why, any help would be appreciated.

```css
.grid-3-10 {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 960px;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-column-gap: 40px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, auto);
}

.content {
  grid-column-end: 11;
  grid-column-start: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-3-10">
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Title</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="grid-3-10">
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent nec mi cursus, faucibus orci sit amet, suscipit urna. Vestibulum bibendum varius ante bibendum imperdiet. Nullam et erat at mi sodales maximus eget nec quam. Orci varius natoque penatibus
      et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec accumsan enim est, et tempus nisl dapibus in. Praesent consequat a nibh quis dignissim. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Donec vitae iaculis dolor. Proin
      imperdiet pharetra euismod. Aliquam nulla erat, hendrerit nec nibh ut, sodales pretium eros.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the reason:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(12, auto);
```

You have set your column widths to be sized based on their content.

Because the content is different in both examples, the sizing will be different.

This will work as you expect:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
```

Now all columns are equal width, based on the free space in the container.

```css
.grid-3-10 {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 960px;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-column-gap: 40px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
}

.content {
  grid-column-end: 11;
  grid-column-start: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-3-10">
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Title</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="grid-3-10">
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent nec mi cursus, faucibus orci sit amet, suscipit urna. Vestibulum bibendum varius ante bibendum imperdiet. Nullam et erat at mi sodales maximus eget nec quam. Orci varius natoque penatibus
      et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec accumsan enim est, et tempus nisl dapibus in. Praesent consequat a nibh quis dignissim. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Donec vitae iaculis dolor. Proin
      imperdiet pharetra euismod. Aliquam nulla erat, hendrerit nec nibh ut, sodales pretium eros.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**revised codepen**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GvajQN)

Here's a cool way to see this behavior play out:

**Firefox Grid Outline**

In Firefox dev tools, when you inspect the grid container, there is a tiny grid icon in the CSS declaration. On click it displays an outline of your grid on the page.

[image]

More details here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Examine_grid_layouts

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot.

Comment: I noticed that in the case of the paragraph content with `grid-template-columns: repeat(12, auto);` - that only 8 columns were shown via the grid inspector - the other 4 were collapsed (and only the grid-gap was shown) - Could you explain why that is happening (and why it's not happening with the h1 element)?

Comment: @Danield, in testing right now, it looks like that is simply a feature of the FF grid inspector (presumably for saving space). I [**added text to the title element**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Mvdbed) and also [**changed the number of columns**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JyqbbK), and the number of collapsed columns *in the grid inspector* varies.

Answer (score -1):

Add `justify-content: baseline;` to the `.grid-3-10`

Example : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ayrZga

Comment: I need it to start in the 3rd column, not the first.

Comment: I edited my answer, let me know if this works for you